# How to assign distinct font, color and style to each sectioning environment of a document?

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, fontspec, titlesec

I am trying to compose with *TeX a document that looks like a GDR manual.
Basically I need to set a different font, style and color for chapter, section, subsection and subsubsection labels.

It is quite easy to change the color and style: I exploited, for instance, specific commands of the `xcolor` and `titlesec` packages (namely `definecolor` and `titleformat`, if you ask).

Since I mainly use LaTeX to compose scientific papers (where the font is quite standard), I just recently started to look for ways to have different fonts inside a document.

According to the information that I managed to retrieve, the easiest way to change the font is to use XeTeX/LuaTeX and `fontspec`. But how am I supposed to change each single sectioning style? I have only found references about how to change the default, `sf`, `sc`, etc. font.

Is there any better way to set font, style and color with respect to my goal? How do I change file size to a give value in points?

Moreover, can I place the "Chapter N" and "Name of the Chapter" parts of a chapter sectioning wherever I want? 
I would like to obtain the same effect as [here](http://www.wizards.com/d20/files/d20ModernTradedressrev.pdf), where "Trade Dress" should be "Chapter N" and "STATEMENT", instead, the "Name of the Chapter".

Comment: Does these commands `\newfontface\sctitle[Color=ff000000]{Linux Biolinum Bold}\titleformat{\section}{\sctitle\Large}{\thesection~}{0pt}{}` (and analogous ones for subsections, chapters...) give the effect that you are looking for?

Comment: It seems it does not load the .ttf files I'd like to use so I cannot say if it works for me...

Comment: Any idea on how to use the Agenda Bold .ttf that is freely available from [here](http://www.ufonts.com/fonts/agenda-bold.html)  from current directory?

Comment: If you are on Ubuntu, just drop the `*.ttf` file on the directory `/home/<your username>/.fonts/` and wait a few seconds. That's what I did anyway. On the other hand, the `fontspec` package offers the option `ExternalLocation`, so you can alternatively use `\newfontface\sctitle[Color=ff000000,ExternalLocation=/font/path/here/]{font name.ttf}`. Mind the last `/` on the font path!

Comment: Hi Guillem, thanks for the kind reply! I'm on a Mac, I don't know what I exactly did, but after an hour of tentatives, I managed to have that font displayed. Later today I will experiment more to see if I get the desired result! Thanks for now.

Comment: As it stands, I'm not quite sure I follow where the issue or issues are here: loading fonts, setting fonts for sections, ... To get an answer, I suspect we'll need an minimal working example (MWE), but also the question might need to be split into parts, some of which might already have answers.